# 401 Unauthorized invalid_grant when refreshing token

Tags: oauth-2.0, coinbase-api

When I try to refresh my access_token with my refresh_token, it gives me an 401 error:

```
invalid_grant 
The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.
```

I am very sure that the refresh token is not expired/invalid because it was OAuthed like 5 minutes ago. It is also not revoked by me.

This is the post request I'm sending (with axios):

```
POST https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token

grant_type = 'refresh_token'
client_id = <CLIENT_ID>
client_secet = <CLIENT_SECRET>
refresh_token = <REFRESH_TOKEN>
```

Thank you for you help.